# What does inheriting from :this() means?

Tags: c#

I am watching a C# course and a part of code caught my eyes which was not explained in the tutorial.

```
Public Product(int productId, string productName, string description) : this()
{
    this.ProductId = productId;
    this.ProductName = productName;
    this.description = description;
}
```

what does `:this()` means in the costructor ?

Comment: It's not inheritance, it means "first of all, call  the constructor requiring no parameters (then proceed with this constructor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:` indicates the start of the initializer list. `this()` invokes the default constructor `Product()`, which could be defined implicitly or explicitly.

If there is a constructor defined, which takes one or more arguments, then there is no default constructor defined implicitly.

Your example constructor `Product(int productId, string productName, string description)` will only compile if there is a default constructor `Product()` explicitly defined in the same class because the default constructor `Product()` is not defined implicitly in this case.

The explicitly defined constructor `Product()` will be invoked before the code in the body of `Product(int productId, string productName, string description)` is executed. If `Product()` is empty (and has no initializer list), it won't do anything.

Comment: Hi Stonar

If I understand it right : this()  should create automaticly the "this.ProductId = productId;...." part ?

Comment: @AndrásCzeitner No, :this will do whatever is written in the parameterless Product constructor.

Comment: So if I get it right while it is empty it is actually won't do anything, but If I define something in this() it will run before the normal constuctor  right ?

Comment: @AndrásCzeitner I have edited the answer. See above.